# Python version of Netcat (follow-up question)

Tags: python

This question is a follow-up of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44962411/netcat-code-from-black-hat-python-book-not-working) topic.

The OP was very likely encountering "Connection Refused". I'm facing it now with the same
code:

```
   #!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys, socket, subprocess, threading, getopt

listen = False
upload = False
command = False
execute = ''
target = ''
upload_dest = ''
port = 0

USAGE = '''
BHP Net Tool

Usage: bhpnet.py -t target_host -p port
-l --listen                           - listen on [host]:[port] for incoming
                                        connections
-e --execute=file_to_run              - execute the given file upon receiving
                                        a connection
-c --command                          - initialize a command shell
-u --upload=destination               - upon receiving connection upload a file
                                        and write to [destination]

Examples:

bhpnet.py -t 192.168.0.1 -p 5555 -l -c
bhpnet.py -t 192.168.0.1 -p 5555 -l -u=c:\\target.exe
bhpnet.py -t 192.168.0.1 -p 5555 -l -e=\"cat /etc/passwd\"
echo "ABCDEF" | ./bhpnet.py -t 192.168.11.12 -p 135
''' 

def usage():
    print(USAGE)
    sys.exit(0)

def main():
    global listen
    global port
    global execute
    global command
    global upload_dest
    global target

    if not len(sys.argv[1:]):
        usage()

    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'hle:t:p:cu:',['help','listen',
                               'execute','target','port','command','upload'])
    except getopt.GetoptError as err:
        print(str(err))
        usage()

    for o, a in opts:
        if o in ('-h', '--help'):
            usage()
        elif o in ('-l', '--listen'):
            listen = True
        elif o in ('-e', '--execute'):
            execute = a
        elif o in ('-c', '--commandshell'):
            command = True
        elif o in ('-u', '--upload'):
            upload_dest = a
        elif o in ('-t', '--target'):
            target = a
        elif o in ('-p', '--port'):
            port = int(a)
        else:
            assert False, 'Unhandled Option'

        if not listen and len(target) and port > 0:
            buffer = sys.stdin.read()
            client_sender(buffer)

        if listen:
            server_loop()


def client_sender(buffer):
    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        client.connect((target, port))
        if len(buffer):
            client.send(buffer)

        while True:
            recv_len = 1
            response = ''

            while recv_len:
                data = client.recv(4096)
                recv_len = len(data)
                response += data
                if recv_len < 4096:
                    break

            print(response)
            buffer = input('')
            buffer += '\n'
            client.send(buffer)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)  # here it prints out "Connection Refused"
        print('[*] Exception ! Exiting ...')
        client.close()


def server_loop():
    global target

    if not len(target):
        target = '0.0.0.0'

    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.bind((target, port))
    server.listen(5)

    while True:
        client_socket, addr = server.accept()
        client_thread = threading.Thread(target=client_handler, args=(client_socket,))
        client_thread.start()


def run_command(command):
    command = command.rstrip()
    try:
        output = subprocess.check_output(command, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
    except:
        output = 'Failed to execute command.\r\n'
    return output


def client_handler(client_socket):
    global upload
    global execute
    global command

    if len(upload_dest):
        file_buffer = ''
        while True:
            data = client_socket.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            else:
                file_buffer += data

        try:
            with open(upload_dest, 'wb') as file_descriptor:
                file_descriptor.write(file_buffer)

            client_socket.send(b'Successfully saved file to {}.'.format(upload_dest))
        except:
            client_socket.send(b'Failed to save file to {}'.format(upload_dest))

    if len(execute):
        output = run_command(execute)
        client_socket.send(output)

    if command:
        while True:
            client_socket.send(b'<BHP:#> ')
            cmd_buffer = ''
            while '\n' not in cmd_buffer:
                cmd_buffer += client_socket.recv(1024)
            response = run_command(cmd_buffer)
            client_socket.send(response)

main()
```

I'd like to ask more experienced network professsional why it could possibly throw "Connection Refused" if the port 9999 is open and firewall isn't blocking it ?

Running it like this:

server-side: `./netcat_repl.py -l -p 9999 -c`

client-side: `./netcat_repl.py -t localhost -p 9999`

Comment: Referenced question got no answer because it failed to give relevant information, mainly the full error stacktrace showing the line that actually raised the error and the Exception itself, along with the command line. If you do not give it either you will not get much more... BTW after a short test I found `AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'` in client_sender at `client.send(buffer.encode())`, but there is way too much code for me to debug it....

Comment: @SergeBallesta  My apologies. I used OP's code as a reference but he didn't convert python2's byte handling into Python3's. I edited my post to reflect my code I use to run. If you run it it will give you "Connection Refused".

Comment: And I still say that there are too much problems in a too long code. The Connection Refused is caused by an indentation error in main: it enters `server_loop` after processing the `-l` parameter and before processing `-p` hence with a 0 port. But there are still tons of inconsistencies of str vs byte string and poor handling of peer closing the connection. Learn to debug with print traces or a true debugger, but there is too much for me.

Comment: @SergeBallesta  Yeah so I fixed the indentation and handling bytes and I got it working.
But I had no idea that the indent was wrong and you pointed me in the right direction. Feel free to post it as a solution and I'll accept it for you. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to have helped you, but it will not help much future readers, so I shall not spend time to write an answer. Feel free to do so if you want.

Comment: Yeah ... wrong indent isn't really a ground-breaking resolution. Anyway, I do appreciate that you chimed in !